# UTF-8 encoding issue with turkish characters in php, ajax, json, jquery ,mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, character-encoding

I am having trouble with the character encoding. I have tried lots of things, but got no result. 
Here is the case: I have some stored procedures in my DB and I send notifications to the users. Here it is:

```
some calculations..
IF @howmanyknew=0 || @howmanyknew>=6 THEN
    SET @memberID=(SELECT userID FROM myDB.users WHERE ticketID=@ID);
    INSERT INTO notifications (senderID,receiverID,messageContent,isRead)VALUES(1,@memberID,"Some turkish characters like ö ç ş ğ ü ı İ",0);
END IF;
```

And here is the structure of my notifications table:

```
id (INT) (PRIMARY_KEY)
senderID (INT)
receiverID (INT)
messageContent (TEXT) utf-8_turkish_ci
isRead (INT)
```

After adding this, a notification ball appears to the user just like in the facebook. When the user clicks it, he/she sees the message:

1. No turkish character, no problem:

   [image: Case1]
2. Some turkish characters: ö,ç,ü. I got this message in the console:

   > (index):167 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of null

   Here, ajax can't get the variables from the back php  page (fetchMessages.php) via `json_encode()`
3. The rest turkish characters: ş,ı,ğ.

   [image: Case 3]

Here is the relevant parts of my `index.php` and `fetchMessage.php`

**IMPORTANT:** Both are coded with "UTF-8 without BOM"

index.php:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<script>
.
.
$.ajax({                
    type:"POST",
    url:"fetchMessages.php",
    data: '{"id":"'+id+'"}',
    dataType: "json",               
    success: function(returnedData) {   
        var n=returnedData.counter;
        $(".content").empty();                  
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            $(".content").append("<span style='display:block;text-align:left;font-size:9px;font-style:italic;background:gray'>"+returnedData.nick[i]+":</span>");                           
            $(".content").append("<div class='divtext' contentEditable>"+returnedData.msg[i]+"</div>");
        }                           
        $(".content").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    error: function(returnedData){
        alert(returnedData);
    }
});
.
.
</script>
```

fetchMessages.php:

```
<?php
    //header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1');
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR');
    include("conn.php");
    //iconv('cp1252', 'utf-8', "\x80 and \x95")-> "\xe2\x82\xac and \xe2\x80\xa2";
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $result=json_decode($input);
    $id=$result->id;
    $result=dbquery("select * from notifications where receiverID=".$id." and isRead=0");
    $senders=array();
    $msgs=array();
    $ids=array();
    $counter=0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $m=$row["messageContent"];
        //$m=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $m), PHP_EOL;
        $msgs[$counter]=$m;
        $ids[$counter]=$row["id"];
        $senderID=$row["senderID"];
        $result=dbquery('select * from usertbl where userID='.$senderID.'');
        $s=$result->fetch_assoc();
        $senders[$counter]=$s["username"];      
        dbupdate("notifications", array("isRead"=>1), array("id"=>$ids[$counter]));
        $counter=$counter+1;
    }
    echo json_encode(array(msg=>$msgs,nick=>$senders,counter=>$counter,ids=>$ids));
?>
```

You also can see the some comment outs in the php page. I have tried them too. But as I said, no result.

**AND** If I convert them from "utf-8 without BOM" to "utf-8" I only get an alert dialog box for the characters in Case 2 above:

```
[object XMLHttpRequest]
```

However, I still get the question mark for the rest.

Comment: You said your PHP files are UTF8.  What about the database?  Is that UTF8 or UTF8MB4?  And is the content of the input fields UTF8?  How is your database connection configured?  Is that been set up to use UTF8 as its character encoding?  There are a lot of places in a software stack where character encoding matters and they all have to be UTF8

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already said that DB is utf-8. you can see it. not the utf8mb4

Comment: Didi you try htmlentities? Is possible for you?

Comment: Did you try using "SET NAMES UTF-8" sql statement?

Comment: @EnesApaydın Thanks. It worked!

Comment: @EnesApaydın Can u answer it so I can mark it? Thanks again.

Comment: @egazi you're welcome, I added answer.

Comment: Did you use the extra argument?  ``json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding

```
"SET NAMES UTF-8"
```

Sql statement just after your connection to database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try enforce your connection using: set-charset

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php